# Define a TypeScript type that takes a lowercase word

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Is there any way to define that kind of type in TypeScript? Something like:

```
type lowercaseWord = /[a-z]/
```

But that defines a string instead? (I think the code above will define a regex.)

Comment: There are no regex types in TypeScript, so there is no specific type that corresponds to "a string composed only of lowercase letters".  You can make a generic type constraint and a helper function.  Do you want to support or prohibit foreign character sets?  [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3zKkN) accepts them and [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpDz7m) code rejects them.  If you want to see either of them as an answer, let me know.

Comment: @jcalz clever solution!

Comment: It's possible to do this with template literal types, but you _really don't_ want to do this. If it's not a hypothethical, perhaps consider sharing your use-case. A branded type might be the best option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no. There is built int (intrinsic) type `LowerCase` but it works as an utility type. It works as `String.prototype.toLowerCase` and not as a regex.
See example:

```js
type Result = Lowercase<'A'> // 'a'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqmAyFjAgJwM5QLxQOQEFcoAfPAISNNwGEiB6OqMVAewDcBLAE2gEMAbflAH8WAdwhco-JCgwAoUJCjxxiZGkw5VE1AGNe6CAB446uegB88xeGjnN2WAlmPSOhwtvKAkunyC4pLGACpQEAAeKAB2XJjowKgc0QDmlk5hkTFxKq4YUAD8UJlRELGYOmgGRqHpRWEAXFDREGxoUE0tbag2eizRCdJBqE6h4aXlUAlJqZYAFNNNfgGiEly1AJTY6dEAroI2dABUR-JQR1AA8gDWZ0d08qtoc7i8uFsMUCy38sen51AAKKoVg9c4PJ6oF6ED6MNCgx7DF4ARneUE+8JYPUhLwAJABSAB6aIxIKxQA)

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1553-L1561) you can find more types: `Capitalize`, `Uncapitalize`, `Lowercase`, `Uppercase`

If you want to apply such restriction it is possible to do in the function:

```js
type UpLetters = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' // provide all allowed letters
type LowLetters = Lowercase<UpLetters>

type Letters = UpLetters | LowLetters

type IsAllowed<T extends string> = T extends Letters ? T extends Lowercase<T> ? T : never : never

const lower = <T extends string>(str: IsAllowed<T>) => null

/**
 * Ok
 */
lower('a') // ok

/**
 * Error
 */
lower('A') // error
lower('1') // error
lower('$%^') // error
```

Please keep in mind that

```js
const x: Lowercase<string> = 'A' // no error
```

will not trigger an error

Comment: Thanks, how can I define a type for *any* lowercase word?

Comment: I think `Lowercase</[a-z]/>`  doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstood the question. You need to wrap your string type into `Lowercase` utility. It is not allowed to use regex expression in type scope

Comment: Note that in your code `lower("123")` is accepted; is that what OP wants?  Prohibiting uppercase letters is not the same thing as allowing only lowercase letters, since letters aren't the only characters in existence.

Answer (score 12):

(Documenting here for posterity, even though the question is slightly different and asks for `[a-z]`)

As of TypeScript 4.8 there is now support for using [the intrinsic string manipulation types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#intrinsic-string-manipulation-types) with wide types like `string`.  This was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47050](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47050) but not mentioned in the [TS 4.8 release notes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8/).

So now, `Lowercase<string>` only corresponds to lowercase strings (strings which remain unchanged after `.toLowerCase()`), whereas in TypeScript 4.7 and below it could match any `string`:

```
let str: Lowercase<string>;
str = "abc"; // okay
str = "DEF"; // error in TS4.8+
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/DYUwLgBAzmBOBcEAyB7A7iWBjAhlEAPDLAJYB2A5gHwDcAsAFDEQC8EARDgEZbs0QB6ARBQBrHAE9GzNuwAiAUQBifQcMywUsCOQgAVAMoAWAHQAOANSMgA)

Comment: Wooow, was not aware about it. Can I mention your answer in my blog ?

Comment: Sure.  It's strange that this wasn't announced in the release notes

Comment: Very strange, because this is super important. Anyway, thank you for providing an answer. I believe, you answer should be accepted

Comment: Btw, if you are aware about another undocumented features, I will be more than happy if you share your knowledge. Thank you